# 24 Countdown Timer 12PM Everyday iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, swift

I need to run a timer that repeats every 24 hours starting at 12pm each day. I am having a lot trouble finding out the proper way to do this. If anyone could post some sample code I would be greatful!

I have it working I just need to add a timer to the NSLog input. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

//assumption: targetTime is after now
    NSString *targetTime = @"12:00";

```
//split our time into components
NSArray *timeSplit = [targetTime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

NSUInteger hours =  [[timeSplit objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
NSUInteger minutes =  [[timeSplit objectAtIndex:1] intValue];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

//split now into year month day components
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [currentCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];

//set our time components from above
[dateComponents setHour:hours];
[dateComponents setMinute:minutes];

NSDate *targetDate = [currentCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

//ensure target is after now
if ([targetDate timeIntervalSinceDate:now] < 0)
{
    NSDateComponents *day = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [day setDay:1];

    targetDate = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:day toDate:targetDate options:0];
}

NSTimeInterval timeRemaining = [targetDate timeIntervalSinceDate:now];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeRemaining];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"hh:mm:ss %@", formattedDate);
```

Comment: What do you need it to do? Do you just want to show the current count down when the user runs the app? What do you want to happen if the user isn't running the app at 12pm if anything?

Comment: I want the timer to countdown to 12PM everyday and then repeat everyday. I want this to work even when the app is not running. I was told I need to use  NSDateFormatter and NSTimer but I am not sure how to put it all together.

Comment: You really need to learn more about the system.  Study up on NSDate, NSCalendar, NSDateComponents, NSDateFormatter (though NSDateFormatter is the class you're least likely to need).  Study up on UILocalNotification.  Study up on NSTimer.  No one's going to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're out of luck. Timers get invalidated when your app enters the background. You'll need to check the time when your app re-enters the foreground and start a new timer that will fire at noon.

To trigger an event when your app isn't running, the best I think you're going to be able to do is a UILocalNotification, which will display a message to the user with the option to invoke your app.

If you build your app for Jailbroken devices you could probably do this, but I don't know anything about jailbroken development.

Comment: I know its possible. I need to use NSDateFormatter to calculate the time from now until 12pm and then use an NSTimer to make it move when the app is running. I just can't find any helpful code on this.

Comment: Not NSDateFormatter, NSCalendar and NSTimeComponents. Do a search in the Xcode docs on "Calendrical calculations." There is a pretty good article on the subject.